# Why do the estimated coefficients in a simple linear regression model have a distribution?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

When we do OLS, as I understand it, we do all our derivatives to obtain some $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ that minimize the SSE (unexplained error between the observed data and the estimated response $y_i$-hat). Since we have optimized the SSE and obtained values for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ then why are they treated as random variables?

[image]

They have a standard error and thus a variance and we can also see a t-value here. Thus they both have a distribution and I do not understand why this is so.

Comment: The estimates coefficients are calculated from a random quantity, correct?

Comment: It is my understanding that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, I assume that's what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two basic ways to see the situation:

1. *Descriptive only*: You want to describe the linear association in your data. To do so, you calculate the regression coefficients and use them as a two-number summary of the association. All good, no reason to study inferential stats stuff like t value. If you want to further reduce to a single number, take the correlation coefficient.
2. *Inference*: You collect a random sample and want to say something about the underlying (much larger) population. Now, you use the coefficients as *estimates* of the true parameters in the population. Every random sample produces other estimates by chance, which gives a distribution. It is statistical magic, why we can say something about this distribution with a single sample, but that is hidden in the many assumptions of the normal linear model.

Put differently: Just because you see a t value, it does not mean that you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

One assumption (!) in OLS is that for *fixed* $X$, the mean response or "ground truth" is $Xb$ for some fixed parameter vector $b$. However, the next assumption is that we do not observe this "ground truth", but an admixture of noise; specifically, for fixed $X$, we only observe $y=Xb+\epsilon$ for iid normally distributed $\epsilon$. If we repeat the data collection for the exact same $X$, we will obtain different observations $y$. Thus, for fixed $X$, the observations $y$ come from a random variable.

We now proceed to *estimate* the unknown parameter vector $b$, since we cannot directly observe or calculate it. This we do based on $X$ and our observations $y$, using the hat matrix:

$$ \beta = (X^tX)^{-1}X^ty. $$

Thus, the *estimates* $\beta$ (note the difference between the estimates $\beta$ and the unknowable true parameters $b$) are functions of the random variable $y$. And therefore, they are random variables themselves. The nice thing about OLS is that we can actually tell what distribution $\beta$ has under the assumptions above.